# Image upload form / image field in a panel pane

Tags: media, panels

There was an [earlier post on this topic](http://goo.gl/VeLrv), but it got no answers and its outdated. 
Is it possible, through any modular functionality, to insert an image into a (mini-)panel, either through token replacement, or through an upload dialog, or through a file selection menu?

I want to build a site with images in a particular layout as a block, and make it very easy for my client to change those images in the future. I can think of some other ways to make this work, but it's driving me crazy that there seems to be no way to simply PUT an image in a mini-panel without having to upload it and hard-code an image tag.

And since my client knows no HTML, coding it this way makes it un-helpful for him. And this mini-panel block is going to be used on a number of pages, and needs to be easily modified.

Comment: While I understand the need to have a simple way to display images in panes, I don't understand the question the way it's currently phrased. Panels, mini or no, deal with layout, they don't store data. I don't see why you should be able to simply "PUT" an image. It needs to be stored somewhere, no? That said, the UX could definitely be improved, but that's not what you are asking about as far as I can tell.